# How can a histogram be transformed into a variety of predefined constituent histograms?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, histogram, fft

Let's say I want to make a meal that has a specific nutritional composition from a variety of ingredients:

```
meal = a * ingredient_1 + b * ingredient_2 + c * ingredient_3
```

A little like how a Fourier transform can transform a waveform into a composition of sine waves, how could a meal (a histogram of nutrients) be converted into a composition of ingredients (other histograms of nutrients) such that a set of parameters can be extracted that describe the quantities of each ingredient to use to get the best 'fits' to the meal?

So, for example, in a Pandas DataFrame, we have a meal and a variety of ingredients:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
                    [        'meal',    1625.14,    90.9,   47.214,  49.962,    138.16,  6.726,           6.606,  28.858],
                    ['ingredient_1',        109,    13.4,        4,     0.9,       4.4,   1.75,             0.3,     134],
                    ['ingredient_2',        126,     0.8,      3.1,      19,       0.5,    0.4,             0.4,     0.4],
                    ['ingredient_3',         35,       8,      0.1,     6.6,         1,    0.1,             0.1,     6.2],
         ],
         columns = [
                             'name', 'calories', 'carbs',    'fat', 'fiber', 'protein', 'salt', 'saturated-fat', 'sugar'
         ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
#A
a1=df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[1:],'calories'].tolist()
a2=df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[1:],'carbs'].tolist()
a3=df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[1:],'fat'].tolist()
A=np.array([a1,a2,a3])
#B
b1=df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[0],'calories'].tolist()
b2=df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[0],'carbs'].tolist()
b3=df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[0],'fat'].tolist()
B=np.array([b1,b2,b3])
#Solve
X = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
df['Quantity']=[X.sum()]+X.tolist()
df_prop=df.loc[1:,['name','Quantity']].reset_index(drop=True).set_index('name')
#Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#for use Jupyter Notebook
%matplotlib inline 
#Draw
ax=df_prop.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,15),fontsize=20)
ax.legend(fontsize=20)
```

Output:

[image]

X contains the amount of each ingredient. If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask!